# Trimming File name to get Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, trim

I was wondering what the best approach to trimming a file name in order to get specific variables would be. For example, the file name is:

> 5000+10-08-2018_Image2.jpg

What I want is the 5000 and 10-08-2018 separate, so I did this:

```
 string input = file.Name;
 int index = input.IndexOf("_");
 if (index > 0)
    input = input.Substring(0, index);
 string newInterval = input;
```

And I get, "5000+2018-02-05". How can I go the next step to get these values separate. I've tried this:

```
     string input = file.Name;
     string input2 = file.Name;
     int indexInterval = input.IndexOf("+");
     int indexDate = input2.IndexOf("_");
     if (indexInterval > 0)
        input = input.Substring(0, indexInterval);
     if (indexDate > 0)
        input2 = input2.Substring(0, indexDate);
     string newInterval = input;
     string newDate = input2;
```

And I get, "5000" and "5000+10-08-2018".

I'm new to coding in C# ASP.NET, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split the string on the separators you indicated.

```
string fileName = "5000+10-08-2018_Image2.jpg";
string[] underscoreParts = fileName.Split(new char[] { '_' });
if (underscoreParts.Length > 0)
{
    string[] plusParts = underscoreParts[0].Split(new char[] { '+' });
    Console.WriteLine($"{plusParts[0]}\n{plusParts[1]}");
}
```

This returns:

```
5000
10-08-2018
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd first use `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`, then `IndexOf` + `Remove`:

```
string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
int plusIndex = fn.IndexOf('+');
if(plusIndex > -1)
{
   string beforePlus = fn.Remove(plusIndex); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to get substring from indexInterval to indexDate.

```
    string input = file.Name;
    string input2 = file.Name;
    int indexInterval = input.IndexOf("+");
    int indexDate = input2.IndexOf("_");
    if (indexInterval > 0)
        input = input.Substring(0, indexInterval);

    if (indexDate > 0)
        input2 = input2.Substring(indexInterval + 1, indexDate - indexInterval - 1);

    string newInterval = input;
    string newDate = input2;
```